# How do I know if DnD succeeded

Tags: java, swing, jtable, drag-and-drop

I implemented DnD between 2 JTables in my java applet.

It works fine: when I drag a line from one table to another (or from a table to itself - reordering), it copies to the destination and removed from the origin.

The problem is when I drag a line outside the java window. The cursor shows like a circle showing that this drag is illegal, exportData() is called anyway, and I don't know how to identify whether the DnD was legal or not?

This is important because only if it was legal, I would want to remove the line from the origin JTable...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are talking about the `TransferHandler` class. Then, `exportData` does only the preparation of the transfer; `exportDone` is the method to override and implement the removal for the case `action==MOVE`. By the way, the API documentation for both methods clearly describes this.